# Treatment of copular verb in dependency parse of Google Natural Language API vs Stanford CoreNLP parser

Tags: dependency-grammar

Basically my question is what is the correct treatment of copular verbs in the following sentence: "The car is red."

According to Google Natural Language API, the root is the verb "is" and the "car" is the nominal subject of "is".

According to Stanford CoreNLP dependency parser, the root of the phrase is "red" and "car" is the nominal subject of "red"

[image: Google Natural Language API dependency parse]

[image: Stanford CoreNLP dependency parse]

Comment: What is "correct" always depends on theory. There is no uniersal agreement on this kind of questions.

Comment: Basically it's all just some theoretical constructs. As long as one theory is self-consistent and is useful for solving some kind of problem, it should be fine. There's no point for different constructs to be the same and there's certainly not really such thing as being "correct" in this case. Another example is different programming languages: as long as they can all be used to solve practical problems and are self-consistent, you wouldn't say there has to be one true "correct" syntax. The same goes for languages.

Comment: Your analogy with programming languages made this very clear to me. Thanks!